# Character pointer's address changing

Tags: c, pointers, memory, char

I am confused about the `const char` pointer.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    const char map[12][24];
    char fileName[] = "map1.txt";
    const char * mPtr;
    mPtr = map;


    printf( "%d %d \n", mPtr, map );

    load_map( fileName, map );

    printf( "%d %d \n", mPtr, map );


    return 0;
}
```

Here is the `load_map()` function code:

```
bool load_map( char * fileName, char * map )
{
    FILE * fptr;
    char c;
    int count = 0;

    fptr = fopen( fileName, "r" );

    if( fptr == NULL ) {
        printf( "Fail to read map \n" );
        return false;
    }

    do {

        c = fgetc( fptr );
        *( map + count++ ) = c;
        if ( count % 23 == 0 ) continue;
        *( map + count++ ) = ' ';


    } while( c != EOF );

    fclose( fptr );
}
```

My question is when execute

```
mPtr = map;
```

and they exactly with the same memory address, but after the `load_map()` function executed 
`mptr`'s value has changed.

But in that function, I do not reference `mptr`. What is happening?

Comment: use '%p' instead of '%d' to print a pointer otherwise you will get warnings

Comment: Indeed, it's possible that you aren't even printing the content of `mptr`, depending on the C implementation. You should include the actual output in your question, as that could provide some insight.

Comment: Ok, apparently I'm the only person who actually read your code ... everyone else was took busy doing language lawyering ... and I should have done so sooner ... see my answer for the real culprit.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is undefined behavior.

The `map` array is declared as `const`, but you write into it in the `load_map()` function, that's just wrong. Why is it `const`, when you obviously expect and intend to change it by loading data into it?

Comment: I think he's trying to highlight the fact that `map` address and `mptr` value should not change. He didn't declare `filename`, the one should be const, with `const`.

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely because you write beyond the bounds of the arrays in `map`, so the data you write out of bounds spill over to the `mPtr` variable.

Also, the variable `map` in the `main` function is declared as an array of arrays, but the `load_map` expected it to be a `char *` (or a single-dimension array). I would be surprised if you didn't get an error or at least a warning about this.

Comment: i think two-dimention array can be seen as a long one-dimention array,

Comment: so i use that to process, i want it to be more concise<br> maybe it just my misunderstand

Comment: @user2706322, a 2D array is *layed out* contiguously, yes, but its type is still not the same. To do what you want you'd have to use a pointer to the first element, something like `&map[0][0]`. But then you'd still have the problem with the constness.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely should switch on all warning levels that your compiler provides. The following line

```
load_map( fileName, map );
```

is undefined behavior. Your are passing a pointer value that is of type `char const(*)[24]` to a function argument that expects a `char*`. These are completely different beast, so no wonder that the result of your executions is somewhat arbitrary.

Any decent modern compiler should have told you.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( count % 23 == 0 ) continue;
```

This test is wrong. You're storing a blank after 22 of every 23 characters, thus surely overwriting the array. It looks like what you really want is

```
     map[count++] = c;
     if ((count % 24) == 23) map[count++] = ' ';
```

And since your input array only has room for 12 groups of 24 chars, you ought to check to make sure that you don't go over ... this is just the sort of code that is a feast for hackers to exploit, to the tune of billions of dollars in losses.

You also have several other problems, as identified in other answers and comments, and a few that no one has mentioned ... for example, you check for EOF in the wrong place ... it makes no sense to read a char, store it in an array, *then* check to see if it was EOF. And it's undefined behavior (you have a great deal of that in this program) to read EOF into a `char` ... c needs to be an `int`.

Comment: thanks a lot<br> i still have a word problem<br>what is language lawer mean? english is not my mother language